# pfSense NAT not passing traffic

Tags: pfsense

I have a pfSense 2.2.6 firewall setup.

```
Public IP: xx.xx.174.162/28
Virtual IP: xx.xx.174.170/32
```

I created a NAT rule setup:

```
WAN     TCP     *   *   xx.xx.174.170   80 (HTTP)   10.0.1.60   80 (HTTP)
```

and a corresponding Firewall rule:

```
IPv4 TCP    *   *   10.0.1.60   80 (HTTP)   *   none
```

When I try to surf up to http://xx.xx.174.170 (or telnet port 80) from the public, it just times out.  In the logs though I see it successfully passed traffic.

From the VPN (or LAN), I can surf up to http://10.0.1.60 with no issue.

Any ideas of what I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Diag>States and filter for xx.xx.174.170:80, what does the state show? Guessing from the description it's probably SINGLE:NO_TRAFFIC, which means it's getting passed in, and the target machine isn't replying or isn't routing its reply correctly. Guessing #2 or 3 here from the description. 
https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Port_Forward_Troubleshooting

Comment: This gave me the clue.  On my server, I had two NICs - one with a public IP address with the public gateway, and one with the private IP I was trying to route to.  The private NIC did not have a default gateway setup.  Once I added the firewall as the default gateway on the private NIC (ignoring the "multiple gateways" warning), NAT started working.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a firewall rule manually then delete it and start from the scratch.
As described in [How can I forward ports with pfSense](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/recipes/port-forwards-from-local-networks.html#accessing-port-forwards-from-local-networks), when you create a NAT rule, there is an option down below called **Filter rule association**, for a default setting, which will create a matching firewall rule automatically. So you don't need to create one manually later. Just check under your **Firewall -> Rules -> WAN** to see if it exists and configured as expected.

Comment: You don't need 1:1 NAT where you have a port forward defined.

Comment: @ChrisBuechler, +1, you are right, my mistake! I have edited my answer.